# Eloquent: Joining Many To Many, Get One Field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

This is how the query would look like in say a usual query

```
SELECT `t3`.d FROM `t1` INNER JOIN `t3` ON `t3`.`t1_id` = `t1`.`id`
INNER JOIN `t2` ON `t2`.`id` = `t3`.`t2_id`
WHERE `td2`.a = 'hi'
```

Where t1 would have many to many to t2, and t3 is the pivot table. The query above would query a "a" column and get the pivot data in column d from the pivot table.

**How can I make a similar query in Eloquent?**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the relationships set up correctly I would think this would work.

```
return t2::first()->where('a','hi')->withPivot('d')->select(array('d'));
```

you may even be able to grab 'd' without withPivot depending on the situation and the many to many relationship. If you are pulling t2 with t1 you should be able to snatch data from the pivot table by default.